# Why does GHC infer type of `IO b` for an application of `hSetBuffering`?

Tags: haskell, typeerror

I am trying to use `hSetBuffering` in a Haskell program using GHC 6.10.
When I try this very simple program:

```
module Ctlc
where

import IO

main :: ()
main = do hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
          return ()
```

I get a baffling error message:

```
ctlc.hs:8:10:
    Couldn't match expected type `()' against inferred type `IO b'
    In a stmt of a 'do' expression: hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
    In the expression:
        do hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
           return ()
    In the definition of `main':
        main = do hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
                  return ()
```

I don't get *why* GHC is inferring a type of `IO b`, since ghci claims

```
Prelude Data.List IO> :t hSetBuffering
hSetBuffering :: Handle -> BufferMode -> IO ()
```

**ANSWER**: I stupidly put the wrong type on `main`. Thanks [ja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15467/ja) for sharp eyes.

Comment: I do wonder why GHC doesn't fail earlier: `()` isn't a monad, and so `do { ... } :: ()` is impossible, even if `hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering :: ()`.  If the error were "can't match () against IO () in main = do ...", you might have noticed the missing `IO` sooner.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've declared main to be of type (), not IO ().

Comment: Thank you **so** much.  Definitely pilot error between the keyboard and the chair.  +1, and I obviously need to think about going to bed...

Answer (score 0):

That function has to have some IO type, because the implementation is going to do a system call.